# Is it possible to control div after select tag changed by css?

Tags: css

```css
select[value="2"]+div{
  background:blue;
  font-size: 20px;
}
select[value="3"]+div{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div>hi</div>
```

I want to control background of div tag, when select changed. Is it possible to use css only?

Comment: No, that is not possible. The select element doesn’t have a “real” value attribute that you could base your CSS selection on, that is only a way of accessing the value of the selected option in JavaScript.

Comment: can you please tell me what are you using angular or any framework or just css

Comment: No, you should use javascript

Comment: okay...so I misunderstanding the the VALUE. Thank you for all answers. 

Comment: It could be done in CSS, if you replace the select element with radio buttons and labels, then the `:checked` pseudo class can be used. The radio buttons would need to be located as previous siblings of the div element in the DOM, but the labels can be put virtually anywhere, grouped into whatever other elements might be necessary to achieve a select-like appearance ...

Comment: so I can use lable and input to create tabs-like, now I think about whether I can use tabs-like and details tag to create a select-like, thank you @misorude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly no, it is not. The CSS attribute selector does not work for DOM properties and the selection of an option does not change those the attributes, only the properties.

I am not sure, if this is applicable to your use case, but one thing you could do is color the div by using the :valid and :invalid pseudo classes.
That would look like this:

```css
select:valid + div {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<select required>
  <option value="">Empty</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div>HI</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible only with CSS. you should create a function with jQuery and call it by `onChange` event

```
<select name="" id="selectBox" onChange='funcChangeCSS()'>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <div id="divhi">hi</div>
```

jQuery:

```
function funcChangeCSS() {
    if($("#selectBox").val() == 2) {
        $("#divhi").css({"background", "blue", "font-size", " 20px"});
    } else if($("#selectBox").val() == 3) {
        $("#divhi").css("background", "red");
    }
}
```

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy, It was not possible only with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

That is impossible. Css cannot monitor changes of select.and you can use javascript to control the background of div tag.

```js
var select = document.querySelector("select");
var div = document.querySelector("#div");
select.onchange = function(){
  var index = select.options.selectedIndex;
  switch(index){
    case 0:
      div.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      break;
    case 1:
      div.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      break;
    case 2:
      div.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<div id="div">hi</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select option {
    margin: 40px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

***If you want to style each one of the option tags.. use the css attribute selector:***

```
select option {
    margin: 40px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

select option[value="1"] { /* value not val */
    background: rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
}

select option[value="2"] { /* value not val */
    background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.3);
}
```

Comment: _“If you want to style each one of the option tags”_ - they don’t; this is absolutely not what was asked for. The `div` element from the given example is to be styled.